# How can I convert a button click with an onload event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-lists, jquery-events

How can I convert this script so that it fires `onload` rather than using a button click?  I'm trying to understand this but it is not sinking in.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(function($){
    // unordered list
    $('button.item').click(function(){
        $('ul').foo();
    });
    
});
</script>
</head>     
<body>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
<button class="item">foo</button>
```

Comment: You want to run a jQuery plugin called `foo` on your list, on load? Just take it out of the click event and there you go

Comment: The body of `jQuery(function() { /* body */ })` already executes on `DOMReady`, which is more or less equivalent to (and usually better than) `load`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<body>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul').foo();
});
</body>
```

Is better if you call it at the end of the file, just befor closing the `<body>` tag.

And the function `$(document).ready(function(){...` is the one you use whn you need to do something when the page loads.

I recommend you to check the jQuery tutorials in w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Document.ready is faster to react than window.onLoad

Comment: Thanks!!! I tried all the methods here.. this seems to be just a little more portable for my use

Comment: indeed using `.ready()` at the end of the document is not needed. the dom is already fully loaded when the script runs...

Answer (score 2):

Use the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function to have the function executed on the onload event :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function(){
       $('ul').foo();    
});
</script>
```

Note that if you don't need to have everything loaded (e.g. sub-elements, mainly images), it's generally better to execute your function as soon as the dom is ready, using [$(callback)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
       $('ul').foo();    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Imagine, `load` event is [*deprecated*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)! :)

Comment: @pst : your construct fires when the dom is ready, not on onload event.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function abc() {
    alert('ok');
}
window.onload = abc;
</script>
```

Comment: you can also do
     <body onload="myFunction()">  
BUT WINDOW.ONLOAD is better

Comment: if you use jquery the window.onload could already contain a function and you're overwriting it...

Comment: yes if jquery is used then its pretty simple 
    $(document).ready(yourfunction () {// Page is loaded.});